# How to include PHP code in CSS?

Tags: php, css

I have a script, and I will be needing to include PHP code in the CSS stylesheet. But when I try adding PHP code in my CSS file nothing occurs! Is it possible?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Rename your CSS file to end in `.php`,

```
styles.css -> styles.php
```

However, I doubt that you really need to have PHP code in a CSS file.

Good point from the comments below, place

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css"); ?>
```

at the top of the file.

Comment: If you do this, make sure to send the correct Content-Type header.

Comment: Thanks now it is more easy now.

Answer (score 16):

Unless it's a terrible lot of dynamic values, it is much better to have a static CSS file, and override only those parts that change dynamically inside the document where PHP is running already anyway. It saves you a request (plus the time needed for bootstrapping etc.), and makes the majority of the style sheet cacheable.

In your PHP/HTML page's head section:

```
<!-- static resource -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

<!-- Dynamic styles -->
<style type="text/css">

  body { color: <?php echo $body_color; ?>; }
  h1   { font-size: <?php echo $fontsize."px"; ?>; }
  p    { color: <?php echo $paragraph_color; ?>; }

</style>
```

Comment: This was such a simple solution and my 2 day headache is finally gone! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried adding this to your `.htaccess`?

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .css
```

http://www.phpro.org/articles/Embedding-PHP-In-CSS.html

Answer (score 2):

Putting PHP code in a CSS file will not work. You will have to create a PHP file first, and let that output CSS code. And also set the correct content type headers.

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/css');
    $color = "#ff6600";
?>

body {
    color: <?=$color?>
}
...
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this

```
<div class="background">
 <p style="color:#fff;">Hello World</p>
</div>

<?php
$color = '#000';
?>

<style>
.background{
    background : <?php echo $color?>;
} 
</style>
```

Comment: How it's different from the [answer directly above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338972/how-to-include-php-code-in-css/73018503#5339001)?