# How to set background-image using img tag

Tags: php, html, css

I have a php method such that it will return an html IMG tag.For example `ImageClass::getImage('sample.png' , 'myTilte')` will return a string as `<img src="sample.png" title="mtTilte" />`

In my css file there is place I used

```
        div.error {
        background-image: url('sample.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
```

How I use `ImageClass::getImage` method to instead of url() method in css for background-image.

Comment: `background-image` (div) and `src` (img) are different.

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably avoid putting php script in your stylesheet if at all possible. But if you really want to, you'll need to let the server know to either

1. Interpret what your PHP outputs as a stylesheet
2. Execute PHP script in your CSS files

Both of these have been answered a few times [across the web](http://www.phpro.org/articles/Embedding-PHP-In-CSS.html) and here on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338972/how-to-include-php-code-in-css), so my answer isn't anything groundbreaking. But I'll repeat the answer for the sake of completeness:

## Interpreting PHP output as a stylesheet

Begin by linking a .php file instead of a .css file. Then set the Mime type in your PHP file so its output is interpreted by the server as CSS. In code lingo, that would look like this:

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.php">
```

**PHP**

Put the following code *before* any text output:

```
header("Content-type: text/css");
```

## Executing PHP script within a .css File

The other method requires some server configuration. On Apache, the easiest way would be adding this to an [.htaccess file](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess.shtml):

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .css
```

This will cause Apache to do the same thing it does inside .php files inside your .css files: namely, look for PHP script and execute it.

Answer (score 0):

you could simply do the CSS inline.

```
<?php 
$image = ImageClass::getImage('sample.png','myTitle');
$bg_img = explode(" ",$image);
$src = substr(strpos('"',$bg_img),strlen($bg_image)-1);
echo "<div style='background-image: url(".$src.");' ></div>
```

I couldn't test this, but I'm sure you get what I mean :)