# How do you add PHP to CSS?

Tags: php, html, css

I was wondering if anyone can help. I am trying to add PHP code, which is retrieving an image from a database, into CSS.

I have the small section of CSS code on my example.php page and need to have different images for backgrounds depending on what variables were posted to the example.php page.

The terrible code that I have come up with is as follows

```
    <style>
    .par-surround {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-image:<?php <img src=<?=$subject['picture']?>border="0" width="740px"         height="auto"/> ?>  ; 
        background-position: center top;
     }
     </style>
```

I don't know if this can be done or if I have to do it a completely other way. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I don't think that's php yo!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338972/how-to-include-php-code-in-css

Comment: Well... I would recommend you to learn the very basic of PHP

Comment: This is a guide on how to render images directly from the database for php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13602259/how-to-display-images-from-database-in-php

Comment: Actually you dont add php to css. Even your question doesnt do this... what you do is you use php in a html construct that contains a stylepart. If you would use this in css, you might had to take a look at `LESS` to handle this. But in your case its simply esplained like LJ_1102 sayed.

Comment: @johnmcg0000 are you serious, why not my answer ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reasodin is correct. You just ned to have a valid PHP code:

```
<style>
    .par-surround {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-image: url(<?php echo $subject['picture'] ?>); 
        background-position: center top;
     }
 </style>
```

Also make sure $subject is defined and has a value, BEFORE you output the CSS code.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done but you need to output proper css to do this.
[`background-image`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp) does not take (invalid)html image tags:

```
 <style>
    .par-surround {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-image: url(<?=$subject['picture']?>); 
        background-position: center top;
     }
 </style>
```