# How to include a PHP object in CSS?

Tags: php, html, css, object, external

When using an *external* stylesheet, is it possible to use a PHP object within CSS - without creating another object?

I have found workarounds with internal and inline CSS (e.g. [How to include PHP code in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338972/how-to-include-php-code-in-css)) Below is some minimal code to show the problem and the workarounds I have found thus far.

in MyClass.php:

```
class MyClass{
    public $color = "blue";
}
```

in PHP/HTML file:

```
<?php
include_once('MyClass.php');
$myClass = new MyClass();
?>
```

... (in head - internal CSS workaround):

```
<style type="text/css">
    h1{color: <?php echo $myClass->color;?>;} 
</style>
```

... (in head - external CSS workaround):

```
  <link rel="stylesheet"  href="external.css") />
```

... (in body):

```
<h1> 1. Internal </h1>
<h2 style="color:<?php echo $myClass->color;?>"> 2. Inline </h2>
<h3> 3. External </h3>
```

In external.css [here is the "problem" - I need to create a new object]:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/css');
    include('myClass.php');
    $myClass = new MyClass(); //<--ANOTHER OBJECT
?>
h3 {
    color: <?=$myClass->color?>;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? So you have to instantiate the object; so what? And to be clear, you *do* have to do that. You can't use an object from one request to the server in a different request. That's impossible. You can save and reload it, in theory, but you can't just reuse it.

Comment: What problem are you having? Have you configured your webserver to run `.css` files through PHP?

Comment: If you need to reuse an object from the original PHP file in the CSS file, you can use a session variable.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar -> I didn't think about a session variable. Indeed the webserver is configured (all the displayed code worked).